# Clone object to $this

Tags: php, object, clone

I would like to ask about PHP clone / copy object to $this variable.

Currently I am new in MVC, I would like to do something like CodeIgniter.

I would like to direct access to the variable.

in my __construct(), i always pass the global variable inside to the new controller (class),

eg.

```
function __construct($mvc)
{
    $this->mvc = $mvc;
}
```

inside the $mvc got config object, vars object.

e.g, currently

```
function index()
{
    $this->mvc->config['title'];
    $this->mvc->vars['name'];
}
```

** what I want is more direct**

```
function index()
{
    $this->config['title'];
    $this->vars['name'];
}
```

I had try

```
function __construct($mvc)
{
    $this = $mvc;
}
```

or

```
function __construct($mvc)
{
    $this = clone $mvc;
}
```

it not successfully. any idea, I can close $this->mvc to $this level?
I try foreach also no success. Please help, Thank!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An elegant solution would be to override [`__get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php):

```
public function __get($name) {
    return $this->mvc->$name;
}
```

`__get()` gets called whenever you to try access a non-existent property of your class. This way, you don't have to copy every property of `mvc` inside your class (which might override properties in your class). If necessary you can also check whether `$name` exists in `mvc` with [`property_exists`](http://de.php.net/property_exists).

Comment: wow.. thanks! this is great! Thx for Galen and Felix help. I really learn a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is what you're trying to do...

```
function __construct($mvc)
{
    foreach($mvc as $k => $v) {

        $this->$k = $v;

    }

}
```

Comment: er... it really odd, just now I also try this way no success, but I try again. It work!. Not sure what happen..@@

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __get($name) 
{
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->mvc)) 
    {
       return $this->mvc->$name;
    }

    $trace = debug_backtrace();
        trigger_error(
            'Undefined property via __get(): ' . $name .
            ' in ' . $trace[0]['file'] .
            ' on line ' . $trace[0]['line'],
            E_USER_NOTICE);
        return NULL;
}
```

I added this for validation.